# markov-chains - Steady-state probabilities with multiple recurrent-classes

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

> The following question is from MIT-OCW, 6.041 Spring (2006), [Tutorial-12](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-041-probabilistic-systems-analysis-and-applied-probability-spring-2006/recitations/tut12.pdf), 2.b.

For the Markov chain below. Assume that the process is in state-3 immediately before the first transition. Then, Find $\pi_i$ for $i = 1, 2, ..., 4$ the probability that the process is in state-$i$ after $10^{10}$ transitions or explain why these probabilities can’t be found.

[image: transition-probability-graph]

The solution [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-041-probabilistic-systems-analysis-and-applied-probability-spring-2006/recitations/tut12_ans.pdf) says - "If you assumed that $\pi_i$ denoted steady state probabilities, then these probabilities do not exist."

**I want to know if the solution is wrong**, since, I can compute the steady-state probabilities as follows:

Let $C_i$ be the recurrent-class corresponding to the recurrent state-$i$, then
$$
\begin{align}
\pi_i & = P_{steady} (state = i|absorbed = C_i)\, P(absorbed = C_i)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: That sentence is definitely false. There are invariant distributions, but there are multiple such distributions.

Comment: @Ian - what is an invariant distribution?

Comment: It's the same as a steady state distribution.

Comment: Dynamically, this chain goes like this: you spend Geo(1/2) time at 3, then you either go to 2 or 4 with probabilities 2/5 and 3/5 respectively. If you go to 2 then you stay in $\{ 1,2 \}$ forever, but you do equilibrate there (because the self-connection from 1 to itself gives aperiodicity). If you go to 4 then you stay in $4$ forever. So to a *very* good approximation, the distribution after $10^{10}$ steps is $2/5$ times the invariant distribution concentrated on $\{ 1,2 \}$ plus $3/5$ times the distribution concentrated on $\{ 4 \}$.

Comment: The error in that is on the order of the largest eigenvalue other than $1$ to the power $10^{10}$, which is *really* small, easily less than $2^{-10^{10}}$.

Comment: @Ian - Yes, that is exactly what I thought (sans the error computation, I straight away assumed it to be steady state), but the official-solution had me confused. So, I guess the solution is indeed wrong!

Comment: I'll point out that there isn't always a steady state; for example if the $\{ 1,2 \}$ subchain was just a deterministic loop then $P(X_n=1)$ and $P(X_n=2)$ would oscillate forever. So it's *possible* that this sentence could be true, this chain just isn't an example.

Comment: Also, if they hadn't told you the initial distribution, then you couldn't get the answer, either.

Comment: By initial distribution, do you mean the starting-state?

Comment: In this case the initial distribution is just at one state but that isn't essential, you could start at a random location, as long as you're told the distribution of the starting state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is wrong. Having been told that you start at $3$ and given this chain, the steady state distribution is $\frac{2}{5}(4/5,1/5,0,0) + \frac{3}{5}(0,0,0,1)=(8/25,2/25,0,3/5)$. This changes if you change the initial distribution (because there are two independent invariant distributions as a result of there being two recurrent classes), but that doesn't mean it simply doesn't exist.

The distribution after $10^{10}$ steps deviates from this by a tiny amount; in particular $p_3$ at this point is $2^{-10^{10}}$. The other probabilities will deviate by similar amounts. For this to work it was important that there is a self-edge from $1$ to $1$, so that the dynamics confined to $\{ 1,2 \}$ are aperiodic.